# incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and ASCII-8BIT SQL Server

Tags: utf-8, sql-server-2014

My environment: Rails 4.2.4 Ruby 2.0 & SQL Server 2014 with a collation of `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` at the database level.

I got an error

> incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and ASCII-8BIT

when the view found in the database some special characters like ç, á, é, etc.

I've had tried some configurations that I read but nothing worked.

I tried this in the view:

```
# encoding: utf-8
```

In the enviroment.erb:

```
Encoding.default_external = Encoding::UTF_8
Encoding.default_internal = Encoding::UTF_8
```

In the application.rb:

```
config.encoding = "utf-8"
```

I tried in view:

```
<td><%=h role.description.force_encoding("ISO-8859-1").encode("UTF-8") %></td>
```

It worked correctly but this way is very difficult. I want something that run in all project, like on models for example

I tried on Role class:

```
   self.column.force_encoding("ISO-8859-1").encode("UTF-8")
```

but not recognize the command

Could someone please help me?

Tanks!

Ale

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem, finally.
A colleague gave me a tip installing the

tiny_tds

gem and ran properly without any of the settings listed above, just set up the database.yml

```
development:
    adapter: sqlserver
    mode: dblib
    database: MyDataBase
    dataserver: MyServer
```

Previously I was using ruby-odbc gem

thanks!